# VisualBasic 2010 - merge 2 strings and read them as a variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, variables, merge

i have this code, and i want to access some variables.

```
Dim k1 as String = "Something"
Dim k2 as String = "Something"
... to k230
```

------------------Then i have this:

```
   Dim rnd = New Random()
   Dim nextValue = rnd.Next(230)     
   For i = 0 To 230
            If nextValue = i Then
                MsgBox('k+i') <--BUT READ THIS AS A VARIABLE.
            End If
i = i + 1
        Next
```

i readed some similar questions, but them doesn't apply to this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `Dictionary`:

```
Dim k As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()

k.Add(1, "Something")
k.Add(2, "Something")
'... to 230

Messagebox.Show(k(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using arrays here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx

> An array is a set of values that are logically related to each other,
>   such as the number of students in each grade in a grammar school.
>
> By using an array, you can refer to these related values by the same
>   name, and use a number that’s called an index or subscript to tell
>   them apart. The individual values are called the elements of the
>   array. They’re contiguous from index 0 through the highest index
>   value.